# Key verification in AES

Tags: encryption, aes

If the user enters a wrong key for AES decryption, some garbage data is generated. I want to verify the given decryption key and throw an error if the key is incorrect. How can I verify the key entered by the user?

Comment: You use it, and see if it outputs garbage.

Comment: ...or you use an MAC, which is the correct approach.

Comment: @spectras how can I check if a set of bytes is garbage or not

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark can you please explain more what is a MAC, please write a proper answer if you can

Comment: @Nilesh if you're using that data, you expect it to have a specific format. Check it. To make that process easier, fixing a specific value at a specific place and checking it is indeed there is a good option, as ShadowRanger wrote in his answer.

Comment: @spectras I am developing a general purpose encryption utility for my summer training, so I may not be able to notice a pattern if other user uses the utility. Also I can't understand the magic number approach can you please explain it.

Comment: The idea is just that if you work with arbitrary data, you prepend some recognizable pattern before encryptring. This way you check (and strip) the pattern upon decryption. HMAC, that Luke describes, goes one step further: it makes the arbitrary data depend on the rest of the content.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72658/how-do-i-detect-a-failed-aes-256-decryption-programmatically/79948#79948 for a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).  The basic premise is that you run the plaintext through an HMAC, add the result to the plaintext and then encrypt.  Then do the opposite when decrypting.  If the plaintext and HMAC result match, then you know you've got the correct key.

OR, if you want to know prior to decryption, use the key material provided by the user to derive two further keys (using, say PBKDF2).  Use one for encryption and another for an HMAC.  In this case, encrypt first and **then** apply the HMAC using the second key.  This way you can compute the HMAC and check if it matches **before** you decrypt.

Comment: the methods you and others are suggesting first decrypt the file then check if the entered key is valid or not, are there methods know if the key is corrects when the user enter the key

Comment: No - think about this for a second, if you could check if the key was valid before decrypting the message you would be able to generate keys and test them.

Comment: KDF + HMAC of the key is a secure solution. It's used quite often.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest approach is to add a magic number to the plaintext file data in a predictable location before encrypting; when decrypting, if the magic number is wrong, you used the wrong key. Downside to this approach is that it cannot validate the integrity/authenticity of the entire message.

To do that, use AES in an authenticated mode (e.g. [AES-GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode)) which gives stronger guarantees that the rest of the message was not tampered with.

Comment: Can you please explain magic number and AES-GCM methods, the link you provided for AES-GCM doesn't explain it properly, I have to implement it as code so I would need a detailed explanation.

Comment: "magic number": add some known text to the message.  When you decrypt the message check for the "known text"; if it's present discard it and continue, if it's not present you have either the wrong key or a corrupt message block.

Comment: @Nilesh: You'll have to do research on your own for AES-GCM. It would take pages of info to reproduce the full spec of AES-GCM in a "more understandable" way, and it's trivially easy to search for this info online. In reality, you should just be using an encryption library that supports AES-GCM directly, and then you don't need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

One common way used to verify if a key is correctly entered, without revealing the actual key, is by use of a **KCV (Key Check Value)**. When you create the key you would at the same time calculate the **KCV**, when the key is then entered manually, you can verify the entry by re-calcuylating the **KCV**. This is eg. used when entering keys manually into HSM's from physical key letters.

To calculate a **KCV** for an AES key you encrypt an empty (0x00) block with the key and the first 3 bytes of the resulting encrypted block is then the **KCV**.

Take a look [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/how-to-obtain-kcv-from-the-key)